# MS Access 3061 Too Few Parameters

Tags: ms-access

I have a very simple update statement but it keeps giving me the 3061 error.

```
Public Function SendToYard(ByVal lEquipmentId As Long)
    oMb.ExecuteSql ("UPDATE Equipment SET GeneralLocation = 'Yard' WHERE ID = " & lEquipmentId)
End Function
```

The table name is Equipment, the column names are GeneralLocation and ID

What could possible be going wrong here?

Here is the ExecuteSql function
Note I am using DAO

```
Public Function ExecuteSql(qry As String)

    db.Execute qry, dbFailOnError

End Function
```

Comment: Using dbFailOnError without an error handler is really quite unwise, seems to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this was a moot question.
The problem was that in SQL design mode, the SQL statement executed correctly because it was using the current database by default.
In my VBA code in the model base class, the DAO.Database object was being set by getting a stored path to the database. It was pointing to the wrong file.
Problem solved.
Bottom line, make sure you know what db is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Function SendToYard(ByVal lEquipmentId As Long)
oMb.ExecuteSql ("UPDATE Equipment SET GeneralLocation = 'Yard' WHERE ID = '" & EquipmentId & "'")
```

End Function

Comment: ID is Autonumber -> Long Integer (tried it, still doesn't work)

Comment: GeneralLocation is Text type, with a 3 value lookup ("Yard";"Garage";"Field")

Answer (score 0):

Try copying and pasting the SQL portion of your code into the SQL View of the query designer. It should show an input box requesting the missing parameter.  I'd be willing to bet there's a typo somewhere, and that should help you find it.

Comment: It actually runs it fine, saying "You are about to update 1 row". I changed the " & lEquipmentId for a 1 resulting in "UPDATE Equipment SET Equipment.GeneralLocation = 'Yard' WHERE Equipment.ID = 1" without the qoutes.